# Splitting problem: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have been facing a small problem with splitting/slicing string :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.example.com'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs='secondaryInfo')

for title in titles:
    print(title)
```

the output is like this :

```
<span class="secondaryInfo">(1994)</span>
<span class="secondaryInfo">(1972)</span>
<span class="secondaryInfo">(1974)</span>
<span class="secondaryInfo">(2008)</span>
<span class="secondaryInfo">(1957)</span>
```

I want to split and get years , every split/slice I try , I get this error :
I tried everything for example :

```
year=title.split(">")
or
year = link.split('>')[1]
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

what am I doing wrong ? how can I get "Years" ex. (1974)

Comment: There is no `split` in the code you provided, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Please post the variation of the code that caused the error

Comment: can you try to change  attrs='secondaryInfo' into class_='secondaryInfo', I think it will return (1994)

Comment: sorry guys , i added the split function

Comment: `print(title[28:34])` or `print(title.split('>')[1].split('<')[0])`

Comment: @sharim-iqbal still nothing : print(title.split('>')[1].split('<')[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @Kouros for title in titles:
    print(title.get_text())

Comment: @d-freak still same results : <span class="secondaryInfo">(1966)</span>

Comment: @Kouros can you give the URL you use in this code?

Comment: Please provide the URL you use in the code, as currently `titles` holds an empty list.

Comment: You could try `title.get_text().strip('()')` which should also remove the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

In this code, titles variable is a list of all the tags and strings that match your filters using find_all(). You can run a for loop  on `titles` and use `getText()` on each element to find the text of the given tag

```
for title in titles:
    print(title.get_text())
```

If you want them to store in a list, you can this code

```
years = [title.get_text() for title in titles]
```

Comment: Looks much better and context makes it easier to understand for everybody - Great, thank you